# Powershell sets environment variable to $false causing strange behavior

Tags: powershell

When I set a environment variable to false, say $foo, both $foo and !$foo result in false.

```
$env:foo = $false
Write-Host (!$env:foo) # False (expect to be True)
Write-Host ($env:foo)  # False
```

Can anyone explain that? Thanks!

PS: The version of powershell

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.1.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.1.3
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19043
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment variable values are always stored as *strings* - you can assign `$false` to one, but PowerShell *will* convert the value to a string (`'False'`).

When converting the string back to a boolean, PowerShell interprets the value as `$true` because the string is **non-empty**:

```
PS ~> [bool]''
False
PS ~> [bool]'True'
True
PS ~> [bool]'False' # string is non-empty = $true
True
```

To parse the string value `'False'` as `$false`, use `[bool]::Parse()`:

```
PS ~> $env:foo = $false
PS ~> [bool]$env:foo
True
PS ~> [bool]::Parse($env:foo)
False
```